# How to exit app on car_undock without BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

i want my app to exist on car UNdocking. For starting it on dock it is enough to write to manifest:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
```

The only thing that worked for me so far is creating a BroastcastReceiver which listens to:

```
"android.app.action.EXIT_CAR_MODE"
```

and within onReceive of that BroadcastReceiver do:

```
uiModeManager.disableCarMode(UiModeManager.DISABLE_CAR_MODE_GO_HOME);
```

then my app exits and i come back to home screen. But that doesnt look so nice to me -> disableing car_mode if car mode exists ....   ;)

Is there another way without using BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: So your app already exits and it comes back to the home screen. What else do you want it to do? What isn't nice about what you're doing? It works, doesn't it. By the way, please make sure you correct "exists" to "exits" where applicable. Those two words mean completely different things, please make sure you're using the right term.

Comment: thank you Stephan Branczyk, i corrected it. Only wondered if this is the way to go or if there is another (easier) way. Its like "i close the door when its closing". Why do i need to disable car_mode when its already exiting?

Comment: Ah ok, I'm beginning to understand. Within the onReceive of the broadcast, you could just start an intent to start the normal home screen. That should give you the same effect I would think.

Comment: thank you stephan, i just did it this way because of another issue: if i take the magnet from the device onResume of my MainActivity gets called, which i dont want. Dont understand why this is happening though. So it coincidentally happend to be as you suggested ;) gotta clearify this behaviour....